# How to verify notifications in Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

How can we test for some notifications send out of class?

For example, in the code below context is an external dependency. While writing Junit, I mock it. Is there a way to verify which of the "sendNotification" call was executed?

```
Class SomeClass{
 JsonRpcContext context;
  public void someMethod(String arg1,String arg2) throws Exception {
    if(someConditionIsMet){
            //Do some stuff
            context.sendNotification("agentservice", "agentconnected", "Agent session started");
     }else{
         //Do Some Stuff
        context.sendNotification("agentservice", "agentnotconnected", "Error occurred on server side for agent session start");
     }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created `context` like this:

```
context = mock(JsonRpcContext.class);
```

Then this should be enough:

```
verify(context).sendNotification("agentservice", "agentconnected", "Agent session started");
```

or

```
verify(context).sendNotification("agentservice", "agentnotconnected", "Error occurred on server side for agent session start");
```

Comment: Wow, so easy. Thanks a lot. Will accept the answer ...there is cap for 10 minutes :)